# How to invoke a Sparkr Dataframe into R code?

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe created in SparkR on an Apache server. I would need to invoke it in an R code to process the data and extract features out of it. Can someone tell me how read the SparkR df into R?

SparkR df:

```
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sparkR.session)
myframe <- filter(read.df(sqlContext, source = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra", keyspace = "abcd", table = "table1")
```

Call the df in R:

```
rawdata <- as.data.frame(myframe)
```

Comment: I haven't worked with `SparkR` and I note that it was removed from CRAN on 2017-10-22. Using `sparklyr`, there are the `copy_to` and `collect` functions to move back and forth between *R* and *Spark* data frames, provided switching packages is an option for you.

Comment: this could help: https://spark.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `collect` function in SparkR.

```
 r.data.frame<- collect(myframe)
```